# Searching for non-hashed data

Tags: postgresql, hash

I have a user table with a password column that uses md5 hash. Over time, some of its hashes were changed to plain text (users asked for immediate password change, without using the method that would apply hash).

I have modest amount of data, i will do it by hand, but i want to know: there's something along the lines of

```
select * from TableName where Column is not hashed
```

or

```
update from TableName 
   set Column = md5(current value) 
where Column is not hashed
```

or something like that?

Comment: Nothing explicitly like that, but md5 produces a 32 character value, so anything that is not that length would not be md5-hashed. You may still need to verify the remaining as it is possible there are plain text passwords that are 32 characters in length. Another note is that you should not be storing passwords using md5 - is it not secure. You may want to look at using the `crypt` function in the pgcrypto extension: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted previously, the use of MD5 for hashing private credentials or otherwise use within the process of authentication and authorization is officially [highly discouraged](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/836068/).

However, your best chance to detect whether a field stores an MD5 value or a non-hashed value and convert it on-the-fly is something like the following:

```sql
UPDATE TableName
SET Column = md5(Column)
WHERE Column !~ '^[a-f0-9]{32}$'
```

There might be remaining ones in case someone really clever guy generated an MD5 hash of something and used that directly as a password. That will not be detectable but authentication must fail on such a case as the stored value would not match the MD5 hash of the entered password at login.

You should also **not think about transferring plain-text passwords** down to the database for hashing and comparison as the attack surface really is pretty high already. Even if you use decent TLS for your database connections who guarantees you that an administrator or attacker hasn't enabled logging *slow* statements with parameters directly at the database?

Instead, the application should use a library to generate a salt **and** salt-hashed password directly and only transfer the salt and hash to the storage. The format specified by [crypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)) is industry accepted (and therefore highly recommended), there are solid libraries for any programming language available and once a certain algorithm becomes deprecated, you can incrementally change it without a coordinated one-shot upgrade.